# Direct Sum of Simple Modules

Tags: commutative-algebra, modules, dedekind-domain

Let $A$ be a commutative ring and $M$ a module of finite length. Under what conditions on $A$ is it true that $M$ is a direct sum of simple modules? Is it true if we assume $A$ to be a Dedekind domain?

I tried to prove it as general as possible, but it seems we need some sort of "inner product" on $M$ to define a complementary sub-module.

Comment: The $\mathbb Z$-module $\mathbb Z / p^n \mathbb Z$ for $p$ prime and $n\geq 2$ is not a direct sum of simple modules, so "Dedekind domain" is not enough. Google for "semisimple ring" (and "semisimple module" if you are fine with conditions on $M$).

Comment: @darij Thank you mr Darij for taking your time to answer this question. This question came up because of something I was reading in Serre. Would you be so kind to look it over and provide an argument without using direst sum of simple modules.